# Mulesoft - Get value of a Consume response

Tags: dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4

In Studio, I have a "Web Service Consumer".

I need get the value "Document".
This is possible?
This format is what "Consumer" returns to me. In postman is an xml and I have no problems, but with this reply I can't get the information

```
{
body:<wsImprXMLResponse xmlns="http://test.es/IC/SERVICE/"><wsImprXMLResult>&lt;?xml version="1.0"?>
&lt;ArrayOfWsLabel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  &lt;wsLabel>
    &lt;Date>2021-08-25T00:00:00&lt;/Fecha>
    &lt;ECB>85468104510201&lt;/ECB>
    &lt;Locs>
      &lt;Loc>
        &lt;Level>1&lt;/Level>
        &lt;Name>Jhon&lt;/Name>
      &lt;/Loc>
    &lt;/Locs>
    &lt;Ref>2021-08-25T15:25:15.4548388+02:00&lt;/Ref>
    &lt;Document>^XA
^LH0,40^FS
^XZ
~DGR:Test,01552,008,
0000000001F0,0FF03FF803F0,1FFCFFF80738,3FFEFFF80618,7FFFFFF80E0C,7FFFFFF80E0C,FF
^XA
^LL1650
^DFTestCPT1.001^FS
^LH20,40^FS
^PW840
^FTO00,200^XGTEST,1,1^FS
^FT000,1100^XGLOGO,1,1^FS
^BY4,3.0^FS
^FX Servicio / producto ^FS
^FT20,580^ADB,36,30^FN1^FA9^FS
^FX Fecha del envio ^FS
^FT65,580^AFB,26,13^FN2^FA8^FS
^FX Origen, Poblacion Destino ^FS
^FT116,580^AFB,26,13^FDde^FS
^FT116,540^AFB,26,13^FN3^FA14 ^FS
^FT116,290^AFB,26,13^FDa^FS
^FT116,260^AFB,26,13^FN4^FA17^FS
^FX Delegacion Destino ^FS
^FT225,580^AGB,120,40^FN5^FA11^FS
^FX Reembolso ^FS
^FT630,560^ADB,36,30^FN6^FA1^FS
^XZ
^XA^XFTESTCPT1.001^FS
^FN1^FD*B2C/ESTD^FS
^FN2^FD25/08/21^FS
^FN3^FDPT VLC-SUR^FS
^FN4^FDVALENCIA^FS
^FN5^FDPT PATERNA^FS
^FN6^FD ^FS
^FN30^FD46468104510247^FS
^FN36^FD^FS
^FN90^FDAAAAAA2101210001^FS
^XZ
&lt;/Document>
  &lt;/wsLabel>
&lt;/ArrayOfWsLabel></wsImprXMLResult></wsImprXMLResponse>,
headers: [],
attachments: []
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't because it is not a tag in the XML of Body, it is a string which contains an escaped XML, but there is no way for the parser to know that. You can use DataWeave to extract that string and transform it to a proper object, but note that you input is invalid, some closing tags are not matching the opening ones. Provided that you fix the input, you can use this DataWeave script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
read(payload.body.wsImprXMLResponse.wsImprXMLResult, "application/xml").ArrayOfWsLabel.wsLabel.Document
```

Comment: Hi @aled, This response is what the integration returns to me (it is what I collect in the "Consume" payload). I have tried with the script that you indicate but it does not work. Why do you return this format to me? What can I do to read the value? Thanks

Comment: Is payload.body a string?

Comment: I'm not sure what format it is, what it returns to me is what you indicate in the post. Thank you